# How to check if two types are the same, ignoring const and reference?

Tags: c++, types, type-traits

In C++, it is possible to use `std::is_same` to check if two types are exactly identical. Is there a way to check if two types are identical except, maybe, a `const` or a `&` modifier? Here is an example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_same<char,int>::value << endl;    // false - OK
    cout << is_same<char,char>::value << endl;   // true  - OK
    cout << is_same<char,const char>::value << endl;  // false - should be true
    cout << is_same<char,const char&>::value << endl; // false - should be true
}
```

Comment: I suspect [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) would probably come in handy if you're planning on implementing some sort of `is_same_enough`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing cv-qualifiers as well as returning a non reference type will be supported from **C++20** onward
[std::remove_cvref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref)

However as of current standard, you can use Type modifications functions in conjunction

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2>
void print_is_same() {
  std::cout << std::is_same<T1, T2>() << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  print_is_same<char, int>(); //false
  print_is_same<char, char>(); //true

  print_is_same<char, std::remove_const<const char>::type>(); //true
  print_is_same<char, std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<const char &>::type>::type>(); //true
}
```

**Or probably create a type alias such as**

```cpp
template<typename T>
using base_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
```

Answer (score 4):

I found an alternative solution: instead of removing const and &, we can add them:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
bool is_almost_same_v = std::is_same_v<const T1&,const T2&>;
```

Indeed:

```
cout << is_almost_same_v<char,int> << endl;    // false
cout << is_almost_same_v<char,char> << endl;   // true
cout << is_almost_same_v<char,const char> << endl;  // true
cout << is_almost_same_v<char,const char&> << endl; // true
```

Comment: It's a nice practical trick, which doesn't require adding lot of `<type_trait>` jargon!

Comment: You'll want to add `volatile` too. ("What about `&&`?" Don't worry about `&&`, since if `T1` is `int&&` and `T2` is `int&`, then `T1&` and `T2&` are both `int&`.) But still, notice that `const` binds tighter than `&`: your `is_almost_same_v<char&, char> == false`. So you need to be looking at `const volatile remove_reference_t<T1>&`.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<TYPE_TO_TEST>, TYPE_TO_COMPARE>` will do the trick. `std::decay_t<TYPE>` also converts array types to pointers to the array members, so `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<int[5]>, int*>` also yields true. But in many cases, this behavior is even beneficial, especially, if your testing requirement is "can be used like a pointer".

Answer (score 0):

To strip only top-level cvref-qualifiers, the answer is simply

```
template<class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool is_same_uncvref_v = std::is_same_v<
    std::remove_cvref_t<T>,
    std::remove_cvref_t<U>
>;
```

or, pre-C++20,

```
template<class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool is_same_uncvref_v = std::is_same_v<
    std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>,
    std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<U>>
>;
```

As Erel (almost) pointed out above, this is equivalent to

```
template<class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool is_same_uncvref_v = std::is_same_v<
    const volatile std::remove_reference_t<T>,
    const volatile std::remove_reference_t<U>
>;
```

Still, this fails to detect the similarity between `int*` and `const int*`, or between `const int**` and `int *const *`. For that kind of similarity, we need [[conv.qual]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#2.sentence-1)'s notion of "similar type." See [Implementing an `is_similar` type trait based on the definition of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722937/implementing-an-is-similar-type-trait-based-on-the-definition-of-the-c-stand) . I implement that trait in my libc++ fork [as follows](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/llvm-project/commit/337f469738c349a6dbc40539c689f99f63ac7285):

```
template <class _Tp, class _Up>
struct is_similar : conditional<
        is_const<_Tp>::value || is_volatile<_Tp>::value ||
            is_const<_Up>::value || is_volatile<_Up>::value,
        is_similar<typename remove_cv<_Tp>::type, typename remove_cv<_Up>::type>,
        is_same<_Tp, _Up>
    >::type {};

template <class _Tp, class _Up>
struct is_similar<_Tp*, _Up*>: is_similar<_Tp, _Up> {};

template <class _Tp, class _Up, class _Cp>
struct is_similar<_Tp _Cp::*, _Up _Cp::*>: is_similar<_Tp, _Up> {};

template <class _Tp, class _Up>
struct is_similar<_Tp[], _Up[]>: is_similar<_Tp, _Up> {};

template <class _Tp, class _Up, size_t _Np>
struct is_similar<_Tp[], _Up[_Np]>: is_similar<_Tp, _Up> {};

template <class _Tp, class _Up, size_t _Np>
struct is_similar<_Tp[_Np], _Up[]>: is_similar<_Tp, _Up> {};

template <class _Tp, class _Up, size_t _Np>
struct is_similar<_Tp[_Np], _Up[_Np]>: is_similar<_Tp, _Up> {};
```