# Implementing an `is_similar` type trait based on the definition of the C++ standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-traits

I am trying to implement a `is_similar` type trait based on the definition given by the standard (details [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#2)):

> Two types `T1` and `T2` are similar if they have cv-decompositions
> with the same `n` such that corresponding `Pi` components are either
> the same or one is "array of `Ni`" and the other is "array of unknown
> bound of", and the types denoted by `U` are the same.

However, I am not sure to exactly understand what it means, and how to implement it:

```
template <class T, class U, class = void>
struct is_similar_base: std::false_type {};

template <class T, class U>
struct is_similar_base<T, U, /* ??? */ >: std::true_type {};

template <class T, class U>
struct is_similar: is_similar_base<T, U> {};

template <class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool is_similar_v = is_similar<T, U>::value;
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cv-decomposition "peels" a type down into alternating layers of `const`/`volatile` qualifiers and pointer/array indirections. Types are similar if the pointer/array indirections are the same (allowing "array of unknown bound" to match "array of `n`") and if the types underneath are the same (ignoring the cv-qualifiers).

So,

```
// every type is similar to itself
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_impl : std::is_same<T, U> { };
// we don't care about cv-qualifiers
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar : is_similar_impl<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::remove_cv_t<U>> { };
// peeling off different kinds of pointers/arrays
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_impl<T*, U*> : is_similar<T, U> { };
template<typename C, typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_impl<T C::*, U C::*> : is_similar<T, U> { };
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_impl<T[N], U[N]> : is_similar<T, U> { };
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_impl<T[N], U[]> : is_similar<T, U> { };
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_impl<T[], U[N]> : is_similar<T, U> { };

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr inline bool is_similar_v = is_similar<T, U>::value;
```

[Godbolt and test cases](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxENwAMpAA6oFhdbT1DE0FvXzU6Kxt7IycXd0VlTFV/BgJmYgJA41NOBJVw2lT0gki7R2cQAGYATkU0jKzg3IV6kusymIqagEpFVANiZA4AcilK62RDLABqcUqddRbiTGYjOexxNwBBMYmpzFn5petgdc2dyXHaSYMZuZ0CAE9PTAB9AmJmQgUz7fOAen%2B00wADdnI9pk8XtM8Appr4jHhhMRIagYQQlKwqOcCJgjJ5hLj7lCtKsDgAVUiQ56kowHACqvy2SwMqhhCleCKR6VeeHxrGmIHhBHQIBAsM5ZPulOmjMq2FmAHZpEqACJzWTbQHTADuB3QdDAwwI0xYy2mzAc/RNyBBAFoAI4GNh4Kh4Zw/ba4/nMInzEm0MnTGUBoNyjbbFlsiVc5GC9mcvnc4i8/n3FqikDLIyoMGvW3vaXrKkZsXZ3NvAsEe7h9ZKlXiRXqyqarbal7KE7TVBUKjTfC95xaE0Aa2s6DhPem3msuOICn%2B6U%2Bj09W29BN9mGJNMDdODVNDe9rkY%2BrJNMaTyNTBOlACoqfTb3WhRfEcjpQ%2B642G02NTi8RufoPDuQY6AeIF7iGEEMkyUbnhysY8nyN7zOS0w6GK96yuhmHPgmiHEB%2Bspfsqap/l6AGEluRwimKvgAF5vCatjgS8u4UqxtIwfK5xwfhl5IWmqHiAArNItiiaqn5iRJInNgqL4IQJhGoZ%2B8r1mRLb/j6QGliADFMdMLHUmxQZQaZR6wae0ZKW%2BgkoTo5KieJknSbIcl4a%2ByZEeGGmNs2rbrlR6a0fpeCMe8Rmcex%2B4mVxxE8SexBnvxdkpshrBFmJrnETJkmebZ3mqQlCrfpprbaYB1HARZHFxTFx5bGgtAtJgAAengotYrDtNMVr6KlyavCChyqoN77FeGYogmwBjURV2yztMRhfLQEDdPW5zTNtwqZmgBjVtsO3HYcOj3ONPIgvcs5UrOX7zOdUiSKJOi0E90zao8mCridO33OdXlXld8w3dMVCsKgvr3Wd8yzJIz0ia973arQqBbb9p0A4VQPXfQpp0C0t14yC%2Bi%2Bki1GlQ9sNPS9b3wx9QJfT9GP/bDgOXbjNoEwQVLg5DJok4S5PQ498O08jQKo%2Bjv2szoF0psDCz0FhS3NS0T7qbLcMI0j9Ofd90snVr7MK5zWF876GuUzDcs04jdOSAz0xS0dLNU3LJvDfcJN4Og0wQLe3QQLOgdUj7fsB0Havnsr3Qi9TYv2xLztohABrfSnJrMJ4BIQkQYMGNcBQWsQwDGMOChx67Mvu/LXsg3jemwh8KxGJhRMmnpPgt6suGa7Xdu647KOpzYmB%2B/nTiQggBwKEGkzMAoleG8dxvYxzDed6F3fLL3IBPmJCNSTCjfb0sre4dlHn9zb2vi3rjMG9XRu157isrxjqvcwHgtk%2BwEB6WOKITC0dpi/zUOwOOYlKiSSge5KSH9fpLXAeTAO0cAGhSAaAfecCYFyTgdwfKN9RY6wdk7JmiDMZs3XqbB6z8MYny5i1AgP9SYQMwBgzMWCQHczAWw8muDYHOREq5Shx1kH8P/redBgCPgnEwoI/BzlCHX2tiQ%2B%2Bz0WxO1Rv7JczAVzO0wOPVEfVZ5BgMlXHYTZhi9FYCAYYIlhikFMMMNwTjUD2LOjIOQ8J%2BiDAOGMTgTiCD2Lcd0XoI4QAADZqgADo3BRKiQADiiZIKJbhOBuEkCkqJQh7HcCcS4txpAPHDCcQoEAHgQmuJsaQOAsAkDtSSAdEg5BKDpGAAoAACiIZQDAECoB1C4oJpA0D4m5AUHpNhWD9MGUUpxYzPDkxcAvUQmS3AeEWcsgA8gdWZQzQlOKacgLYpcKllNIMc1I%2BAXFOJoPQJgbAOA8H4IIYQwCJDeJkEIPADgKmQF6KgTwBRzl2gAOpsAFHaDMcxVSfNkDITgipyl%2BKGIIDM1gpl9IGQc4YQTbH2Mcc4w5JT7FtRSXaKJ3BTTvOANMTJ8T4nTGwG1ZpRAUQQFwIQEgcNKicA2l4hF0hgmHPCaQGezAsAuHWqQSJlQ3CxOqJUPllRFQ1CSdURUnBKjcEqHk4YBTiU1NJRcipVTRUEuGJIQpJLSkipqWKsE85/CuCAA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: @Vincent Yes. I managed not to make a test case for that, but the penultimate test case checks whether a `const volatile` pointer-to-member is similar to an unqualified pointer-to-member. E.g. `is_similar_v<int *const, int*>` is `true`.

Comment: Nicely done. One suggestion: In its current form, it will continue to recurse as long as it can find parallel decompositions of the two types, even if the remaining sequences are identical. I guess a quick-and-slightly-dirty optimization would be to add `template<class T> struct is_similar<T, T> : std::true_type { };` so that it stops earlier when it encounters identical types (or change the structure a little bit so that it really stops as soon as possible).